# Map area onclick - prevent border from highlighting

Tags: html, dictionary, onclick, area

I have a mapped image on my site, and when you click on each defined area the site displays different div content within the prescribed portion of the page.

Currently, when you click on each area the border briefly highlights blue. There's an onclick="blur()" command that prevents the border from REMAINING highlighted, but I'd prefer it didn't highlight AT ALL. I've scoured Stack and the internet but can't find an answer to this seemingly simple question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried to style the outline property of the area elements via CSS?

```
area { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS:

```
image {
    outline: none;
}
```

You also have to make sure that your images are not in any `<button>`s or `<input>`s, because those will also hive an outline. Use the same CSS for those.